# Change color of Bootstrap Delete Text X Icon in FormControl

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, form-control

Is it somehow possible to change the color of this "x" in React?
The element is a FormControl with the type "search"

[image]

```html
 <div className="w-25 input-group my-2">
            <FormControl
              type="search"
              placeholder="Suchen"
              aria-label="Search"
              onChange={(e) => searchItem(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
```

Comment: could you provide your code

Comment: you mean this what I have added?

Comment: when I copy your code I can see just an input without any icon

Comment: Have you clicked in it and written something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the color of `X`, but can use `-webkit-search-cancel-button` pseudo-element to customize it. in below example I've used `font-awsome` as background to customize it but you can do it by whatever you want.

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/svgs/solid/times-circle.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that will do it :)